# SSH from A through B to C, using private key on A

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, bash, proxy

These is my scenario:

- Host C is not accessible from A.
- Host B is accessible from A.
- Host C is accessible from B.
- Both B and C have `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (from A) in `authorized_keys`
- B does not have the private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`), since it would be a security risk (the key is personal).
- since B doed not have the private key, it is not possible to login to C from it

How can I use the key in host A to login to host C? Is this possible? I fear not.

(similar but different to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/337274/91978))

### EDIT

What I would need is a way to provide, on-the-fly (stdin or similar), the private key to the ssh hop in B, without it ever touching the filesystem in B. Is this possible?

Comment: make ssh tunnel over host B.

Comment: You say "B does not have the private key (~/.ssh/id_rsa), since it would be a security risk". Why? Are there multiple users that connect to _the same_ account in B? Is it feasible to create multiple accounts in B (one for user) so to have private keys in B, too?

Comment: @MrShunz not to the same user, but several users can become root ...

Comment: @IporSircer cool! How? Beware: private key is not in host B.

Comment: @IporSircer that's what I thought at first, but if I understood correctly, he cannot connect from B to C via keys.

Comment: I don't understand why the answer from the linked question doesn't also apply. Just use agent forwarding.

Comment: @MrShunz: that's why he should create a tunnel on host B to host C, then he can ssh from A to C via the created tunnel and using private key on host A.

Comment: @IporSircer sure! But if he can already connect from B to C then it's a non-issue. That's the solution proposed on the linked answer. That's why I assumed he _cannot_ connect from B to C, quoting the OP "since B does not have the private key, it is not possible to login to C from it".

Comment: Making ssh tunnel to port 22 of host C doesn't mean it's connected. It's only a portforward where he can make ssh connection from host A to host B directly. Type `man ssh` to know more about ssh tunnels. Tunnel only tries to connect to host C, when he start using the tunnel. He can forward also port 80 or any other. It's only a portforward, not an authenticated connection.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a recent version of OpenSSH you can simply type:

```
ssh -J B C
```

If you are using a slightly older version without `-J` support you can use a slightly more elaborate syntax:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p B' C
```

If you need this every time you ssh from A to C it can be useful to add an entry in your `.ssh/config` file looking like this (in recent versions):

```
Host C
   ProxyJump B
```

Or like this (in slightly older versions):

```
Host C
   ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```

Using either of the above you can simply type `ssh C` to open the connection. This is particular useful when you are using `ssh` indirectly through one of the many tools which utilize `ssh` for their transport. Not all of these tools provide a straightforward way to pass command line flags to the `ssh` command.

Comment: You can also automate this by creating ~/.ssh/config (on A), and adding an entry for `Host C` with the option `ProxyJump B` (or `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B` as appropriate). Then `ssh C` will do the right thing.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's a good point and particular useful in case you aren't invoking `ssh` directly but rather indirectly through another tool which uses `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

That's rather easy. Just use agent forwarding (-A option on ssh).

Sample:

```
#On machine A use
ssh -A user@<machine_B>
#Then on machine B use
ssh -A user@<machine_C>
```

No need for copying private keys all over the place. -A forwards only any SSH Agent requests over to the first machine in the chain, so a private key on machine A can be used as long as you don't switch users on intermediate machines.

If you change your user on machine B (e.g. with a su foo to user foo), the agent forwarding does not work any longer, as the next connection is done as user foo with it's own keys.

Comment: This will give B access to use any keys in that agent for as long as the connection stays open. There are methods to combine it all into a single command being invoked on A without agent forwarding, which means they will be more secure and usually also more convenient.

Comment: But just if someone impersonates that user on B. Didn't know about -J, so good point, but does this allow for using different usernames on B than on C? Sometimes we have servers with differing usernames but same keys (e.g. admin_server and admin_poi or something along this line)

Comment: I think you can use a syntax like `-J user@hostname` (the machine I am on at the moment has a too old version of ssh to have `-J` so I can't test it right now).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question while looking for the same thing. The solution here with keys looks like:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i /path/proxy.pem -W %h:%p user@proxy_host" -i /path/target.pem user@target_host`

I can't take credit here though, as this solution is from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1535108/ssh-inline-proxy-jump-using-keys-is-not-working), but I have verified that this approach works.